# Какие вопросы на собеседовании могут задавать по mobx и redux/flux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux, mobx

Собственно интересует какие вопросы на собеседовании могут задавать по mobx и redux/flux?

Comment: Могут спросить о птичках и почему они летают клином. Реальный мой вопрос на собеседовании. Любопытно, интересно, нестандартно, отсеивает вытесанных только для шаблонов "разработчиков". Это я к тому, что вопросы могут быть любыми; если Вы знаете тему, по которой экзаменуетесь, вопросы не имеют смысла. Всё это ИМХО.